# bug in forloop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

I'm pretty new to webdesign and also to Javascript. While setting up my first web application I run into a bug that I don't understand. It must be something in the way I think Javascript works in webpages or something that I don't know about loops in general.

I'm trying to highlight the best value of a table using js. As long as the file is running locally on my PC, I generate random values and keep pressing the refresh button until a bug occurs. For debugging purposes I also use the console.log function now, but I still don't understand way this is happening...

Many thanks to any hint about what could be wrong in this actually pretty simple code.

```
// Best value of the week
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var bestValue = 0;
var bestRow = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < 22; i++) {

   if (table.rows[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML > bestValue){
       bestValue = table.rows[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML;

       console.log(i);
       console.log(table.rows[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML);
       console.log(bestValue);
       bestRow = i;
   }
   else{
       console.log(i);
       console.log(table.rows[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML);
       console.log(bestValue);
   }
}

table.rows[bestRow].childNodes[5].classList.add('bestofweek');
```

[image: print screen]

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: What *is* the bug? You've explained how you reproduce it but not what is wrong. I see code and a screenshot but nothing obviously wrong. There are console logs but they don't really help me.

Comment: I'll delete the code that I consider as not useful for my question. What is wrong is that I expect the highest to be marked value, and 974 is definitely not the biggest number in this table.

Comment: You are comparing strings, not integers. "innerHTML" returns string, not a number. Just add parseInt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AndrewShmig said you are comparing string with int and should use parseInt to convert innerHtml to int first. 
To explain why not parsing it to int do not work in your case,

in the first iteration:

> When comparing a string with a number, JavaScript will convert the string to a number when doing the comparison.

So "6555" > 0 will be true as 6555 > 0, but now you are assigning the bestValue with string "6555" and its no longer an int.

Now subsequent comparisons are between two strings, which are done alphabetically:

```js
"451" > "6555" // false, because 6 comes after 4 alphabetically
"8995" > "6555" // true
"9359" > "8995" // true
// ...
"974" > "9359" // true, because 7 comes after 3 alphabetically
//...
```

And now you have the wrong value as your max value.

Ref. [Javascript comparisons](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's perfectly clear!

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings, not integers. [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) returns string, not a number.

Just add `parseInt`:

```
if (parseInt(table.rows[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML) > bestValue){
       bestValue = parseInt(table.rows[i].childNodes[5].innerHTML);
```

Comment: Yes! That solved it, but now please help me to understand why it worked most of the time and why sometimes it didn't? But for sure it makes a lot of sense that comparing string to int must create some issues but I'd expect issues all the time.